# BlackBerry Dynamics SDK iOS v. 8.0 crash app

Tags: ios, swift, blackberry, blackberry-dynamics

I did new enterprise application for BlackBerry Dynamics servers. I did register at Blackberry and take a free trial for BlackBerry UEM server Cloud (for test purposes).
Any way, after all stages with activation device etc., my application got Crash on application "Activation" stage.

[Screenshot of application stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPvTG.png)

And all that I see is:

> 2020-08-07 12:33:44.731071+0300[833:223904] [BBD] INF         UI          GDSplashViewController:viewDidDisappear: (animated = NO) <GDSplashViewController: 0x1441b5c00>
> 2020-08-07 12:33:44.731429+0300 [833:223904] [BBD] INF      UI          GDEProvisionProgressViewController:viewDidAppear: (animated = NO) <GDEProvisionProgressViewController: 0x14680ea00>
> 2020-08-07 12:33:44.975148+0300[833:224066] [BBD] INF                   UnifiedProvisionHandler::processCurrentState 8
> 2020-08-07 12:33:44.975312+0300[833:224066] [BBD] INF                   UnifiedProvisionHandler::performKeyExchange
> 2020-08-07 12:33:44.975444+0300[833:224066] [BBD] WRN                   osid is missing in the BCP url, using enrol as the default value
> 2020-08-07 12:33:44.975580+0300[833:224298] [BBD] WRN                   PolicyStore initDB return
> 2020-08-07 12:33:44.975796+0300[833:224298] [BBD] WRN                   PolicyStore initDB return
> 2020-08-07 12:33:44.975943+0300[833:224298] [BBD] INF       POL         PProcessor::currentStatus - 0 0 0 0 0
> 2020-08-07 12:33:44.976122+0300[833:224298] [BBD] WRN                   PolicyStore initDB return
> 2020-08-07 12:33:45.002959+0300[833:224066] [BBD] ERR b64_and_aes256_encode_with_iv:2279:Failed to encrypt data
> 2020-08-07 12:33:45.003124+0300[833:224066] [BBD] ERR SpekeEnrollmentManager:: Error encoding user id : 61449
> 2020-08-07 12:33:45.003331+0300[833:224066] [BBD] ERR speke_negotiator_create:63:failed to generate client keys, unknown error
> 2020-08-07 12:33:45.003421+0300[833:224066] [BBD] ERR ProvisioningSpekeEngine:314:Failed to create key negotiator
> 2020-08-07 12:33:45.003498+0300[833:224066] [BBD] ERR provisioning_create_context:2127:Failed to create enrollment engine
> 2020-08-07 12:33:45.003559+0300[833:224066] [BBD] ERR SpekeEnrollmentManager:: failed to create enrollment context : 22 (833,0x16ba37000) malloc: *** error for object 0x16ba36b80: pointer being freed was not allocated (833,0x16ba37000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Is any one knows hot to fix it?
Thanks for any help.

Update 12 August 2020:

My best guess, that something wrong with FIPS when Xcode build app for mobile device. Because for Simulator with same steps - everything is ok. – Igor Polishchuk just now    Edit    Delete

Comment: My best guess, that something wrong with FIPS when Xcode build app for mobile device. Because for Simulator with same steps - everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please get a copy of the logs?

Here is how to configure detailed logging in the XCode console. https://docs.blackberry.com/en/development-tools/blackberry-dynamics-sdk-ios/8_0/blackberry-dynamics-sdk-ios-devguide/psc1489681493135/kej1489679360615/iot1490818261994

Comment: Hello. As I understood, GDConsoleLogger | GDFilterNone - is detail logging. So its already turned on. This is all logs, that I got.

Comment: I meant, I want to see all the logs. Whatever you see in the xcode console.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set "Build Settings" -> "Linking" -> "Dead Code Striping" to NO